# Firebase project is not generated

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to create new Android project with Firebase it shows error while creating project in Firebase.

[image]

Comment: You cannot use Firebase word in your project name, it is reserved.

Comment: for a tutorial you can visit https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I think that only applies to names **starting** with `Firebase`. But unfortunately given the answer that Ian just posted, we can't test. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Firebaser here: There is an issue right now with project creation in for Firebase and Google projects in general: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17026

The team are working on a fix, but please check back in later and you should be able to create again.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a Tip regarding adding Firebase in your App.If you are using Android Studio then go to Tools-->Firebase. It opens Firebase Window Next to your Page. Suppose you want to add Firebase Real-time feature.Just click add Firebase and Link Firebase, this will insert the extension for Firebase which will definitely work.Also while adding them, it will ask for the Project creation on Firebase, within from Android Studio.
There either you can create one or select a previous one.
Hope this helps, share doubts if any..!!