# Cannot create a free project on Firebase

Tags: angular

I'm having some issues when I try to create a new project.

You have exceeded the maximum number of free projects that you can create. Try deleting some projects via Project settings or request a project limit increase.

I don't have any project in my console.

Please advice,

Comment: You might have some projects on the Google Cloud Platform. It's all connected you know. Google Cloud Platform, Firebase, DialogFlow etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase project is not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556710/firebase-project-is-not-generated)